# Shuffling a deck of cards?

Tags: c++, algorithm, shuffle, playing-cards

I am *very* new to C++ and I still haven't wrapped my head around the basic concepts yet but my professor wants us to write an algorithm to shuffle and display a deck of cards and the deck needs to be represented as a 2d array.

However I am having trouble just simulating the deck of cards!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<char> deck;
    char suit[] = {'h','d','c','s'};
    char card[] = {'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'};
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            deck.push_back(card[j] suit[i]);
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've seen a lot of card programs with classes but I'm not even sure if we are going to learn those this semester.

Comment: You can combine the suit and value into a structure.

Comment: `deck.push_back(card[j] suit[i]);` - what char do you expect `card[j] suit[i]` to be?

Comment: For shuffling, I *would* recommend `std::random_shuffle`, but that defeats the point. Keep that in mind, though, instead of making your own when you need to trivially shuffle something.

Comment: Are you sure that "the deck needs to be represented as a 2d array" is a requirement? It sounds like a really unusable way to represent a *deck* of cards (which is one-dimensional by nature).

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple struct, you could edit your code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Card {
  char suit, number;
  Card(char aSuit, char aNumber) : suit(aSuit), number(aNumber) { }
};

int main() {
    vector<Card> deck;
    char suit[] = {'h','d','c','s'};
    char num[] = {'2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','T','J','Q','K','A'};
    for (int j=0; j<13; j++) {   
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            deck.push_back(Card(suit[i], num[j]);
        }
    }

    // now, deck[0] to deck[51] hold all the cards
    // first card's suit is deck[0].suit, number is deck[0].number

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should use a struct to represent a card. See for instance [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)

For the shuffling algorithm, here is a hint : if you can shuffle a deck of n-1 card can you shuffle a deck of n cards ?

Comment: We know that you can shuffle a deck of n cards. Therefore it is possible to shuffle (by your argument) n-1 cards. But this argument falls down because you cannot shuffle one card.

Comment: You can too shuffle one card. It's the identity transformation. Just because it doesn't feel like shuffle doesn't make it the wrong definition.

Comment: Indeed, and the algorithm I thought about has been mentionned in the comment by [bames53](http://stackoverflow.com/users/365496/bames53) provided in an other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it complicated?

A pack of cards contain 52 elements. Each element can be denoted by two characters. As mentioned in your post the suit and the (for want of a better word) number. Construct that array. You do not need the expense of vectors etc. The size of the array is fixed. 52 items, each item 2 characters.

Then have a loop - run that look as many times as you wish.

Each time around the loop chose two items between 0-51 (remember in C++ world things start at zero). Those two numbers are random (see [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)). Swap them (both characters - or preferably use a `struct`).

Comment: Using this algorithm for shuffling, it is not possible to guarantee that every permutation has the same probability. The result will actually strongly depend on the initial order of the cards in the deck.

Comment: @VincentNivoliers - I would be interest in seeing this mathematical proof of this statement.

Comment: My calculator says there are 8x10^67 possibilities. So why not generate all those an pick one. If you shuffle a pack of cards and I do likewise (despite the initial order) it will very next to impossible for your set of cards to be in the same order as mine.

Comment: A more typical shuffle algorithm is to iterate through the list once, at each iteration swap a random element from the beginning 'unshuffled' portion of the list with last element of the unshuffled portion and then decrease the unshuffled portion by one (so the shuffled portion grows at the end). This is the modern version of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @EdHeal A random permutation has 52! possibilities. Using 52 arbitrary pairwise swaps yield 52^52 possibilities. Since these numbers are not equal and since the smaller number doesn't divide the larger, the probabilities cannot be the same.

Comment: @eh9 - I did not say 52 pair swaps. Read the post. Make the loop as large as you like. Just start with the pack in the usual order and swap random pairs until that loop is done. Could be 1000 or 12 or whatever. Anyway Vincent where is this proof. Eh9 - there is no perfect algorithm for being random in computing.

Comment: @bames53 The algorithm you describe is the one in the Bentley book.

Comment: No amount of random pair swaps ever yields the same probability distribution as a random permutation, because 52! does not divide 52^N for any value of N. As N gets large, the probabilities do converge, admittedly.

Comment: eh9 - Please rephrase that. 8x10^67 is a large number. Yes they converge. So what! For practical purposes they are random in the sense that humans cannot predicate the order if we use this algorithm). No two humans since cards have been invented (discovered?) have managed to shuffle cards that are in exactly the same order. I would be VERY interested if you can furnish me with a mathatical proof of this convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Go read Jon Bentley's *Programming Pearls*. In the first chapter there's an algorithm for generating random permutations. The algorithm generates each permutation with equal likelihood, and what's more, by the end of reading it, you'll understand why.

His algorithm uses a single index for the permutation. In your case, use N=52 and generate your two indices by the (integer) quotient and remainder after dividing by 4. The quotient gives you a card index; the remainder gives you a suit.

Comment: (is that Edinburgh?) - Have you seen Darren Brown (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTEhOLDa7nQ). Nearly beat it. Also computers only do an approximation of random.

Comment: @EdHeal Please go read up on pseudorandom sequences and their cryptographic versions to understand why "perfect randomness" for this question is a red herring.

Comment: One little question - can a computer (that is deterministic) produce a random number? It cannot. It is deterministic.

Comment: @EdHeal but you can read 'randomness' from an external source and use that in an algorithm.

Comment: @bames53 - We are entering the field of Philosophy. Is anything random? Does God play dice?

Comment: @EdHeal OK, now I insist you go read the Wikipedia article [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). If you can distinguish one of those from a truly random generator (for any definition of "truly"), then you have a magic computer that you should do something more productive with.

Comment: @eh9 = I have read that article - But is nature random? That is a philosophical question. Physics is having that debate. Mathematics has predicted certain things that should occur in our universe. Then the Scientists have found them! - See Brian Greene (Elegant Universe) is an interesting book to read. There is a difference between unpredictable and that is random.

Comment: The whole point of the security definitions for PRNG is that they are make the question of ontological randomness moot. It's an important property, because it means I don't need to care about the philosophical question. Nor do I need to discuss it.